# I got IntegrityError with Bid system in my project Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

**Django Error:**
IntegrityError at /Post/18/bid
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_bid.bidWon
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Post/18/bid
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_bid.bidWon

> I am trying to apply this Specification:

- If the user is signed in and is the one who created the listing, the user should have the ability to “close” the auction from this page, which makes the highest bidder the winner of the auction and makes the listing no longer active.
- If a user is signed in on a closed listing page, and the user has won that auction, the page should say so.

**but when I runserver i got this error**

Please take a look at my code:

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# bids Close Bid
path('Post/<int:id>', views.viewList, name='viewList'),
path("Post/<int:id>/bid", views.take_bid, name="take_bid"),
path('Post/<int:id>/close', views.closeListing, name="closeListing"),
]
```

model.py

```
# DONE
```

class Post(models.Model):

```
# data fields
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
textarea = models.TextField()

# bid!!!!!!!!!!!
startBid = models.FloatField(default=0)
currentBid = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

imageurl = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="No Category Yet!", null=True,  blank=True)

creator = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="all_creators_listings")

watchers = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, blank=True, related_name='favorite')
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# for activated the Category
activate = models.BooleanField(default=True)

buyer = models.ForeignKey(
    User, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title} | {self.textarea} |  {self.date.strftime('%B %d %Y')}"


class Bid(models.Model):
         auction = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_id")
         user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         bid = models.FloatField()
```

views.py

```
def viewList(request, id):
# check for the watchlist
listing = Post.objects.get(id=id)
if listing.watchers.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    is_watched = True
else:
    is_watched = False
context = {
    'listing': listing,
    'comment_form': CommentForm(),
    'comments': listing.get_comments.all(),
    'is_watched': is_watched,
    'Bidform': BidForm()
}
return render(request, 'auctions/item.html', context)

def is_valid(bid, listing):
if bid >= listing.startBid and (listing.currentBid is None or bid > listing.currentBid):
    return True
else:
    return False


@login_required
def take_bid(request, id):
listing = Post.objects.get(id=id)
bid = float(request.POST['bid'])
if is_valid(bid, listing):
    listing.currentBid = bid
    form = BidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    newBid = form.save(commit=False)
    newBid.auction = listing
    newBid.user = request.user
    newBid.save()
    listing.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("viewList", args=[id]))
else:
    return render(request, "auctions/item.html", {
        "listing": listing,
        "Bidform": BidForm(),
        "error_min_value": True
    })

def closeListing(request, id):
        listing = Post.objects.get(id=id)
        if request.user == listing.creator:
                listing.activate = False
                listing.buyer = Bid.objects.filter(auction=listing).last().user
                listing.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('viewList', args=[id]))
        else:
                listing.watchers.add(request.user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("watchlist_list"))
```

item.html

```
 <!-- Close Listing -->
<div class="close-btn">
{% if  listing.creator == user %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'closeListing' listing.id %}" role="button">Close</a>
{% endif %}
</div>

                    <div class="newbid">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    {% if listing.currentBid is None %}
                        {% if listing.creator != user  %}
                            <p class="text-muted">Start the first Bid!</p>
                        {% else %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% elif listing.buyer is not None %}
                        {% if listing.creator == user %}
                        {% if listing.buyer == user %}
                        <p class="text-muted">You've won this auction!</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                            Current price: {{ listing.currentBid }}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if error_min_value %}
                        {% if listing.currentBid %}
                            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Your bid must be bigger than {{ listing.currentBid }}</div>
                        {% else %}
                            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Your bid must be equal or bigger than {{ listing.currentBid}}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %} 

                    {% if listing.activate and listing.creator != user %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form action="{% url 'take_bid' listing.id %}" method="post">
                            <br>
                            <small class="text-muted">Edit Your Crunnt Bid:</small>
                            <br>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ Bidform }}        
                            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
                                <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-1"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>                    
                    </div>         
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
                    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">log in</a> to start the Bid!
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                </div>
```

Comment: The `Bid` model you posted doesn't have a "bidWon" field, have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to ensure your DB is in sync with your code?

Comment: @IainShelvington I didn't use "bidWon" in my code why I have to add it?

Comment: The DB is complaining about `auctions_bid.bidWon` being null, `auctions_bid` is almost certainly the table for your `Bid` model. Did you delete a field and forget to migrate? Your DB tables are not in sync with your models

Comment: @IainShelvington so how can I make my table in sync? if it will help

Comment: Use migrations - `python manage.py makemigrations <app>` to create migration files when your models change and `python manage.py migrate` to sync the changes to the DB. Have you not been running migrations at all?

Comment: or i just have to add this line of code `bidWon = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)` at my model.py file?

Comment: It would stop this particular issue but not in an ideal way, although you'll need to remove `null=True` as the DB is currently complaining that the column can't be null

Comment: @IainShelvington is there any problem with my views.py code or item.html?

Comment: @IainShelvington the weird error disappeared finally, But I want to ask, the winning message that I've been adding above doesn't appear why?

Comment: One problem you have is that your templates are a mess, the nesting and repeated if tags make it a pain to read. The winning message will show when `listing.creator == user` and `listing.buyer == user`, I don't imagine that are a lot of people winning their own auctions?

Comment: @IainShelvington How can I fix this problem? or if you have a better way of writing this logic please share it!

Comment: @IainShelvington I just want to achieve the Specification above I don't have any idea about how to do this but I just try at code above!

Comment: if I want to represent if statement at my template in the views.py function how can I do this?

Comment: I have another problem with the "close" button when I click on it I git this error by djaogo `AttributeError at /Post/22/close 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`

Comment: `listing.buyer = Bid.objects.filter(auction=listing).last().user` - if there were no bids then `.last()` will return `None`, you need to handle this case. As for the template you need to focus on the specification you have and work out how to remove the duplicated conditions so it's simple, you check `listing.creator` against `user` four or five times surely you only need to do it once to show the close button

Comment: sorry, i don't git it what you mean with "I have another problem with the "close" button when I click on it I git this error by djaogo `AttributeError at /Post/22/close 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`"

Comment: The line `listing.buyer = Bid.objects.filter(auction=listing).last().user` in the view `closeListing` has the error, that's what I was talking about

Comment: can I ask? what is the better way to write the if statements inside the HTML file or views.py and if you can give me some hints, please

Comment: Given your spec you really only have three conditions. 1. The user is the creator, show the close button or details of the auction. 2. The user is the highest bidder, show the winning message if it's closed or the form. 3. Otherwise just show the form if the auction is open. A lot of your if tags can be removed

Comment: @IainShelvington I rewrite the function again but I faced some problems i add them inside the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862616/i-got-this-django-error-multivaluedictkeyerror-while-clicking-on-view-button